# How to test Django REST Framework filter using "now"?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Others have explained why writing tests which depend on the current time is a bad idea (for example non-reproducible errors and not being able to test special dates such as summer time transitions). So when testing serializers I've used the following pattern:

```
def test_should_be_valid_if_best_before_a_future_date(self) -> None:
    serializer = MyModel(
        data={
            'best_before': datetime.datetime(…),
            …
        },
        context={'now': datetime.datetime(…)},
    )

    self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid())
```

This pattern makes it trivial to test what happens when, for example, `best_before` is before, at, and after now.

I've not found a similar pattern for filters - they don't seem to have a `context` property. How would I do similar tests for filters, ideally without mocking anything, since that makes the test depend on an implementation detail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually mock time, but when I do I use [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun):

```
from datetime import datetime
from freezegun import freeze_time

@freeze_time("2019-01-21 01:00:00")
def test_time():
    assert datetime.now() == datetime(2019, 1, 21, 1, 0, 0)
```

> ideally without mocking anything in datetime, since that makes the
>   test depend on an implementation detail?

Freezegun won't make your test depend on implementation details because it works on a very low level of the Python api.